# Is there a word to describe a sample of DNA that can be sequenced?

Tags: molecular-genetics, terminology, dna-sequencing

This is a question about terminology. I want to know if there is a word that is used to describe a sample as "able to be sequenced".

My rough guess would be "sequencable". But that does not seem to be a word. "Viable" would be my second guess. But seems to imply a lot more than that it can be sequenced.

What is used in practice?

Comment: As always with adopting general English words to scientific use, the exact context is crucial. What do you mean by the opposite “unable to be sequenced”? Do you mean the DNA is too degraded or has been converted chemically through age, do you mean it is contaminated with DNA from bacteria etc, or do you mean it is one of many repeats?

Comment: But if you change your spelling to "sequencEable" you'll find that it was entered by someone in Wiktionary in 2019 (https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sequenceable). Apparently it has been used in a mathematical sense for many years (https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=UywypI5sjvgC&pg=PA253&lpg=PA253&dq=sequenceable&source=bl&ots=uOkYs-DZ1j&sig=ACfU3U271_SuaKnQ6PqdoSHYRFdHjTq_YQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjezLGx06n9AhWFSMAKHZhkBy8Q6AF6BAgiEAM#v=onepage&q=sequenceable&f=false). A Google search for "sequenceable DNA" finds it in Scientific American.

Comment: @David is correct; sequenceable is definitely a word; it has been used in the biological sciences for quite some time now. I can find published papers using the word dating back to 1996, so probably earlier than that even.

Comment: I think you should request migration of this question to the [English language](https://english.stackexchange.com/) Stack. It's off topic here I think, but definitely on-topic there.

Comment: I'd just delete the question, given the trivial nature of the answer. As a regular user of SE English Language and Usage, I don't imagine they would think much of it.